# How to change class in ul using mootools onclick

Tags: class, onclick, mootools

I'm using mootools to do this: i have a ul that looks like this

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="option">TEXT</a></li>
    <li><a class="option">TEXT</a></li
    <li><a class="option">TEXT</a></li>
    <li><a class="option">TEXT</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to have the class to change when a li has been clicked from 'option' to 'option-selected', my current code looks like the following

```
$$('li.option').addEvent('click', function(el){
    this.toggleClass('option-selected');
});
```

This does work but my issue is how to on click event have the other li class' revert back to the class option and leave the current clicked li class set to option-selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function () {
    var list = document.id('menu'),
        os = 'option-selected';

    menu.addEvent('click:relay(li .option)', function (e, el) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.getElements('.' + os).removeClass(os);
        el.addClass(os);
    });
}());
```

can play with it / tweak it here. http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/nYEkj/

it anchors to the ul element, only attaches 1 event to that via event delegation. depends on what your strategy is - adding the classes to the li or to to As

Comment: Exactly what I was after, thank you for taking the time to help me with this matter.